# Gitlab avoid user login via SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

When I create a user on Gitlab, it creates a regular user on linux and it can login using a regular SSH protocol with same password an user.

How can I disable the SSH login using SSH to desired users? All my server is exposed to that users.

Thank you

Comment: Do these users need ssh access at all? E.g. do they need to access the git repo through ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `sshd_config` file adding this line

```
DenyUsers username1 username2 username3 username4
```

> ```
> DenyUsers
> separated by spaces. Login is disallowed for user names that
> match one of the patterns. â*â and â?â can be used as wildcards
> in the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID
> is not recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users.
> If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are
> separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from
> particular hosts.
> ```

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-deny-ssh-access-for-certain-user.html#ixzz3QkT71bsV

Answer (score 0):

In case you need more than just the login, you can now block SSH as a all:

See [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#block-git-access-protocols-at-group-level) (June 2022)

> ### Block Git access protocols at group level
>
> To improve security, you can now block Git access protocols that you don’t use at the group level.
>
> This is similar to the GitLab administrator setting, but can now be set per
> group.
>
> By default, both HTTP(S) and SSH are enabled.
> In your group’s **Settings > General > Permissions**, scroll to **Enable git access protocols** and remove any protocols you don’t use.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_1/protocols.png -- Block Git access protocols at group level]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#restrict-git-access-protocols) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/365601).